# Java Runtime, Perform some action on closing a application

Tags: java, runtime.exec

We can open Notepad or Calculator or any application using Java Runtime say for example To open calculator we need to run below line of code in java.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("calc");
```

but I want to do some action on closing the app that I opened through above line of code.

1. Is there anyway to perform something on onClosing application?
2. How to check whether application is opened or not?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html would give you more options (see also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html)

Comment: `exec` return a `Process` instance so I think you can deal with this process like destroying it

Comment: Windows. i believe Runtime, ProcessBuilder, Process are common for all. only command will change right?

Comment: Did you try `task kill`?

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("calc");
proc.waitFor();
```

waitFor will wait for the termination of the application. If you don't want to wait, you can call `proc.isAlive()` to test the process status. You can also start a java thread that will start the application and wait for it's termination.

Comment: running `exec("calc")` unfortunately causes the code to continue even after `proc.waitFor();`. The calculator though, will still show up even if the program is **terminated**. Looking for confirmations that this is most likely a case peculiar to my machine only.

Comment: @payloc ok, I haven't tested it on every OS, just on Windows 7.